# deprecated warnings while using boost.spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to write some parsers with boost.spirit.qi but when i am compiling i am getting the following deprecated warnings:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/iostreams/detail/is_dereferenceable.hpp:12:0 ... 

#pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (bool_trait_def.hpp) is deprecated

#pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (template_arity_spec.hpp) is deprecated
```

Am i using the wrong parsers or something old? How can I get rid of these warnings?

EDIT: The `/usr/include/boost/iostreams/detail/is_dereferenceable.hpp` is somehow included by `/usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp`
I am using Boost Version 1.61

Comment: It's rather difficult to tell you what you're doing wrong when you don't show the code (or at least the part of it with include directives). There's also more than 1 version of boost in existence, so it would be useful to indicate which one you're actually using. Finally, `boost/iostreams/detail/...` doesn't look like `boost.spirit` (althought it could possibly be included, there are a few iterator classes i see that depend on things from iostreams).

Comment: I have the same warnings. They're annoying. I hoped they'd be gone in boost 1.61. Perhaps you should report them at the mailing list/boost trac/github repo for boost spirit

Comment: The real culprit here is Boost.Iostream, which Spirit uses internally. As of Boost 1.61, Boost.Iostream is still using Boost.TypeTraits's deprecated header files (`bool_trait_def.hpp` and `template_arity_spec.hpp`). This issue is reported at [Ticket #11886](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11886).

Comment: For a shift, you can mark `/usr/include`, where your Boost header files are located, as a system directory by specifying the GCC (or Clang) command-line option `-isystem /usr/include`. All warnings, other than those generated by `#warning`, are suppressed for header files in system directories. Refer to [The C Preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) for more details.

Comment: @dkim that certainly doesn't fix it for me; `#pragma message()` is clearly also exempt. I know because I run with `-isystem` since forever

Comment: @sehe I have checked again that the stopgap works with Clang (included in Xcode 7.3.1). GCC's `-isystem` appears to work differently than Clang's. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue using the boost geometry package and could not upgrade boost to fix the error.

Disable boost deprecated warnings with the below define:

```
#define BOOST_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_HEADERS
#define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS
```

Note the second define handles a common warning that occurs alongside of the deprecated warning and may not be needed.